# Script to restart a program every few minues

Tags: batch-file, restart

I've tried restarting a program every few minutes with a batch file which looks like the following. However it only opens the `.exe` a lot of times which causes them to crash. Anyone knows why this problem occurs?

```
@echo off                           
:loop                               
start "programm" "D:\Downloads\programm.exe"  
timeout /t 1200 >null               
taskkill /f /im "programm" >null    
timeout /t 7 >null                  
goto loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate a short answer, but it's an easy and quick fix. `null` is nothing, use `nul` as it's almost certainly skipping the invalid output name.

So the code:

```
@echo off
:loop
start "programm" "D:\Downloads\programm.exe"  
timeout /t 1200 >nul
taskkill /f /im "programm" >nul
timeout /t 7 >nul
goto :loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
taskkill /f /im "programm" >null
```

Remove the `>null` and look why it doesn't kill the program.